# Iterate over a collection of strings using LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, string, collections, iteration

I put the following code segment in .NET Fiddle but it printed out `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereArrayIterator1[System.String]` I'd like to print out each content in result, in order to understand how Select works. Can someone please help to point out what the problem is? Many thanks!

```
string[] sequ1 = { "abcde", "fghi", "jkl", "mnop", "qrs" }; 
string[] sequ2 = { "abc", "defgh", "ijklm", "nop" };
var result =sequ1.Select( n1 => sequ2.Where(n2 => n1.Length < n2.Length) );

foreach( var y in result)
{   
    Console.WriteLine(y);   
}
```

Comment: What exactly should your code do?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're expecting that LINQ statement to do.  But essentially you're selecting a list of references to an enumerable from a `.Where()` clause.  What *should* `result` contain?

Comment: `y` is going to contain an *enumerable collection* of all the items in `sequ2` that are longer than which ever member of `sequ1` you are looking at. Obviously you can't just `Console.WriteLine` a collection. But what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: you can try `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", y));`

Comment: `Where` returns `IEnumerable<int>`.`Select` returns `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is return type of given Func. so it becomes `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>`  as suggested by Mike_G you can use `SelectMany` instead to unwrap this to single `IEnumerable<int>`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: `Where returns IEnumerable<int>` Where (no pun intended) do you get that idea? `Where` in this context will return an `IEnumerable<string>` So you end up with an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>` which, for each item in `sequ1` contains the strings in `sequ2` that are longer than it.

Comment: oops. string. sorry @MattBurland

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are actually returning a collection of collections.

```
sequ1.Select( n1 => sequ2.Where(n2 => n1.Length < n2.Length) );
```

For each element in sequ1, this statement filters sequ2 to find all of the elements from the second sequence where the current value in the first sequence is shorter than it and then maps to a new collection containing each of those results.

To describe what Select is actually doing:

- You start with a collection of things.  In your case: `sequ1` which has type `IEnumerable<string>`
- You supply it with a function, this function takes an argument of the type of thing you supplied it with a collection of and has a return type of some other thing, in your case:

  `fun n1 => sequ2.Where(n2 => n1.Length < n2.Length)`

  Your function takes a `string` and returns an `IEnumerable<string>`
- Finally, it returns a result containing a collection of each element in the original collection transformed to some new element by the function you supplied it with.

So you started with `IEnumerable<string>` and ended up with `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>>`.

That means you have a collection for each value that appears in sequ1.

As such, you would expect the result to be:
{{}, {"defgh", "ijklm"}, {"defgh", "ijklm"}, {"defgh", "ijklm"}, {"defgh", "ijklm"}}

You can inspect the results by adding another loop.

```
foreach(var y in result)
{
    foreach(var z in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(z);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your Select to SelectMany:

```
var result = sequ1.SelectMany(n1 => sequ2.Where(n2 => n1.Length < n2.Length));
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong, but I think the OP wants to compare both arrays, and for each element, print the longest one.

If that's the case, I would do it as follows:

```
var result = sequ1.Take(sequ2.Length)
                  .Select((n1, i) => 
                      (n1.Length > sequ2.ElementAt(i).Length) 
                      ? n1 
                      : sequ2.ElementAt(i));
```

Explanation:
Use Take to only go as long as the length of the second array, and avoid nullreference exceptions later on.
Use Select, with two arguments, the first is the string, the second is the index.
Use ElementAt to find the corresponding element in `sequ2`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this example is about to help you to understand how select work. A more simple exmaple what i think is this.

```
public class Person {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
    }

    public class Test {
        public Test() {
            List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
            persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Person1",LastName = "LastName1" });
            persons.Add(new Person() { Name = "Person2",LastName = "LastName2" });
            var getNamesFromPersons = persons.Select(p => p.Name);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not quite sure how that's an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are beginning c#, you need to sideline the keyword "var" from your code.

Force yourself to write out what the variables really are:

If you forego the use of var, you would have seen why your code was Console.Writing what it did.

```
    string[] sequ1 = { "abcde", "fghi", "jkl", "mnop", "qrs", };
    string[] sequ2 = { "abc", "defgh", "ijklm", "nop", };

    IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> result = sequ1.Select(n1 => sequ2.Where(n2 => n1.Length < n2.Length));

    foreach (IEnumerable<string> y in result)
    {
        foreach (string z in y)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(z);
        }
    }
```